# How to exclude module from server vue bundle

Tags: webpack, vue-loader

I want to use velocity-animate in my vue single file component, however I couldn't figure out how to configure webpack to call a [null-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/null-loader) on it.  It seems as though once vue-loader takes control over any `*.vue` file, none of the other loaders are triggered.

The only solution I could get working is a dynamic require wrapped in a `process.env.VUE_ENV` defined variable e.g.

```js
let velocityAnimate = 'not here'
if (process.env.VUE_ENV === 'client') {
  velocityAnimate = require('velocity-animate')
}
```

though I would much prefer a configured approach so I can just

```js
import velocityAnimate from 'velocityAnimate'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I gave this another attempt and landed on a slightly hacky<sup>1</sup> solution using [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader)

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'string-replace-loader',
    options: {
      search: "import animate from 'velocity-animate'\n",
      replace: '',
    },
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Hacky because it doesn't parse an ast.  You could easily add a loader which does though - the concept remains the same.